# Setting Back Button in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller

So I have 3 View controllers : V1, V2 and V3.  When I press a button on V1 it shoots me over to V3. I would like to keep the "Back Arrow" but change the text there. I have tried many things but the word back either reapers when the view is shown or my code does not work.

Any Suggestions?

I already used this code

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "YO", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

let backbutton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
backbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "BackButton.png"), forState: .Normal) // Image can be downloaded from here below link
backbutton.setTitle("Back", forState: .Normal)
backbutton.setTitleColor(backbutton.tintColor, forState: .Normal) // You can change the TitleColor
backbutton.addTarget(self, action: "backAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backbutton)

func backAction() -> Void {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

I tried creating my Button with this code I found on Stack But the button disappeared and the back button appeared in its place again.

Comment: The text that appears for the back button is set by the title of the previous view controller

Comment: `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)` try this with in `viewDidLoad` and already there are lot of question related to this.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah I am aware of that. When the view shows up the new text appears there but then all the sudden the words Back replaces it.

Comment: @Bunty Madan  I tried this but it isn't working in my case. I don't know if it has to do with the fact  I am skipping V2?

Comment: @JakeC if possible then share your demo project

Comment: @ Bunty Madan I only have my main project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` to a button of your own design.  That overrides `backBarButtonItem`, and iOS will not replace your text with "Back".  But if you want an arrow you would have to design it yourself as part of your button.

In my code I set the button whenever the title is changed:

```
override var title:String? {
    get {
      return super.title
    }
    set {
      super.title = newValue
      if (navigationController?.childViewControllers.count > 1) {
        let backButton = // ... custom button
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: "backAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
      } else {
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
      }
```

Comment: I actually tried doing that and the button pops up then disappears and the back button reappears again. I Updated my code above with the button I created

Comment: This answer works great. I just need to make a custom back button now. If you have time to do that please post it! Thanks

Comment: I started with [this button tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/designing-for-ios-taming-uibutton). It's Obj-C but not hard to Swiftify